# javascript validation on drop down lists

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have two dropdown lists to select value from 0 to 23. What I want is that when the user selects a value from the first list, he cannot select a value lower than this value in the second list.

How should I add validation through javascript here? !!

```
<select name="hourfrom">
    <option value="0" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "0" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >0</option>
    <option value="1" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "1" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >1</option>
    <option value="2" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "2" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >2</option>
    <option value="3" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "3" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >3</option>
    <option value="4" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "4" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >4</option>
    <option value="5" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "5" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >5</option>
    <option value="6" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "6" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >6</option>
    <option value="7" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "7" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >7</option>
    <option value="8" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "8" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >8</option>
    <option value="9" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "9" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >9</option>
    <option value="10" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "10" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >10</option>
    <option value="11" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "11" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >11</option>
    <option value="12" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "12" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >12</option>
    <option value="13" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "13" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >13</option>
    <option value="14" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "14" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >14</option>
    <option value="15" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "15" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >15</option>
    <option value="16" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "16" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >16</option>
    <option value="17" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "17" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >17</option>
    <option value="18" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "18" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >18</option>
    <option value="19" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "19" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >19</option>
    <option value="20" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "20" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >20</option>
    <option value="21" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "21" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >21</option>
    <option value="22" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "22" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >22</option>
    <option value="23" @(Request["hourfrom"] == "23" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >23</option>

    </select>
```

To:

```
    <select name="hourto">
      <option value="0" @(Request["hourto"] == "0" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >0</option>
    <option value="1" @(Request["hourto"] == "1" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >1</option>
    <option value="2" @(Request["hourto"] == "2" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >2</option>
    <option value="3" @(Request["hourto"] == "3" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >3</option>
    <option value="4" @(Request["hourto"] == "4" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >4</option>
    <option value="5" @(Request["hourto"] == "5" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >5</option>
    <option value="6" @(Request["hourto"] == "6" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >6</option>
    <option value="7" @(Request["hourto"] == "7" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >7</option>
    <option value="8" @(Request["hourto"] == "8" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >8</option>
    <option value="9" @(Request["hourto"] == "9" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >9</option>
    <option value="10" @(Request["hourto"] == "10" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >10</option>
    <option value="11" @(Request["hourto"] == "11" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >11</option>
    <option value="12" @(Request["hourto"] == "12" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >12</option>
    <option value="13" @(Request["hourto"] == "13" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >13</option>
    <option value="14" @(Request["hourto"] == "14" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >14</option>
    <option value="15" @(Request["hourto"] == "15" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >15</option>
    <option value="16" @(Request["hourto"] == "16" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >16</option>
    <option value="17" @(Request["hourto"] == "17" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >17</option>
    <option value="18" @(Request["hourto"] == "18" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >18</option>
    <option value="19" @(Request["hourto"] == "19" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >19</option>
    <option value="20" @(Request["hourto"] == "20" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >20</option>
    <option value="21" @(Request["hourto"] == "21" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >21</option>
    <option value="22" @(Request["hourto"] == "22" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >22</option>
    <option value="23" @(Request["hourto"] == "23" ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") >23</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why not simply populate the second list _after_ the user selected a value from the first? or repopulate the list after the first select has been changed?

Comment: Have you tried anything??? I see no javascript code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Index of the selected option

```
document.getElementById("to").onchange = function(){
if (document.getElementById("from").selectedIndex > document.getElementById("to").selectedIndex){
    alert("You cannot select less than from");
    document.getElementById("to").selectedIndex="0";
}
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/PYSeJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zWwTQ/1/) of how this could be done:

```
var hourFrom = document.getElementsByName("hourfrom")[0];
var hourTo = document.getElementsByName("hourto")[0];

hourFrom.onchange = function(){
    var from = parseInt(hourFrom.value, 10),
        toOptions = hourTo.options,
        toOptionsLength = toOptions.length;

    while(toOptionsLength--){
        if(parseInt(toOptions[toOptionsLength].value, 10) < from ){
            toOptions[toOptionsLength].disabled = true;
        }
        else{
            toOptions[toOptionsLength].disabled = false;
        }
    }
};
```

We're basically disabling all options before the hourFrom for hourTo.

Answer (score 0):

I have just provided the example just update it as per your requirement.........

```
    <script>
    function check(hourto)
    {
        from=document.getElementById("hourfrom").value;
        to=hourto.value;
        if(to>from)
        {
            alert("From should be less then false");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }    
    }
</script>
From:
    <select name="hourfrom" id ="hourfrom">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
To:
<select name="hourto" id ="hourto" onchange="check(this)">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: creating global variables, not stopping the event-flow as is supposed to (remember: return false !== stopPropagation + preventDefault)...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment: it's pretty easy to achieve this, by repopulating the to-element when the from value changes. [**I've set up this quick fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqXHA/) that does just that.

Obviously, you'll have to wrap this in a `onload` handler in real life, but the idea remains the same... Here's a slightly different version of the fiddle's code:

```
document.getElementById('hoursfrom').onchange = (function()
{
    //create closure reference to to element, so there is only 1 DOM query
    var toElem = document.getElementById('hoursto'),
    vals = (function(max)
    {//this just returns an array [0,1,2,3,...,23]
        var r = [], i = 0;
        while(i <= max)
        {
            r.push(i++);
        }
        return r;
    }(23));//change 23 to whatever max you need here, and the array will be adjusted
    return function(e)
    {//this is the actual handler, returned by IIFE
        var newVals = vals.slice(parseInt(this.value, 10)),//slice from full vals array, only valid values will be used
        //this allows for both from and to to have the same value, if you want to change that:
        //var newVals = vals.slice(parseInt(this.value, 10) + 1);
        options = '<option selected="selected">Now select a TO value</option>',//adds a default first option
        i;
        do
        {
            i = newVals.splice(0,1)[0];
            options += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }while(newVals.length);
        toElem.innerHTML = options;
    };
}());
```

With this code, you can have the to-element populated (or not)... as you want. You might want to look into ways of preserving whatever value the user selected in the to element (if possible). It's not that hard, just use `toElem.value` prior to setting the innerHTML, and change the `options` string (`options.replace('selected="selected"', '').replace('value="'.toElem.value.'"', 'value="'.toElem.value.'" selected="selected"')`) for example...